# PHP Ternary statement within Associative Array to set both key & value?

Tags: php, arrays, ternary-operator

I've been searching and testing for some time and just can't find if what I am trying to accomplish is possible the way I'm going about it.

I would like to add a key/value pair to an array, when defining the array, based on an ternary statement.

```
Array(
    'Item 1' => 'Some value',
    (FALSE)? NULL : 'Item 2' => 'Another Value'
)
```

My expected/wanted behavior is for the result to then be:

```
Array (
  [Item 1] => Some value
  [Item 2] => Another Value
)
```

And when the statement is True:

```
Array(
    'Item 1' => 'Some value',
    (TRUE)? NULL : 'Item 2' => 'Another Value'
)
```

Yield:

```
Array (
  [Item 1] => Some value
)
```

But instead I get:

```
Array (
  [Item 1] => Some value
  [] => Another Value
)
```

Which causes problems since A) I don't want this second element to exist in the first place and B) The False condition value is assigned to the True conditions value (in this case NULL, which sets the key to NULL [])

This is very peculiar. Is my only option to have a standard if(){} statement and Pop the element if the condition is false (by using !) into the array?

Note: Having a null value for Item 2 is not acceptable, rather if the initial condition is true, no element should exist at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 99% sure that this isn't possible, i.e., that you need to use `if`.  I'll think about it a bit more and see if I can do better.

Comment: It is not possible. Either you add an element to an array or you don't; there is no way to do it conditionally like this. What exactly is the problem with using an `if` statement, anyway...? It does the job perfectly (some would even say it is more intuitive than a ternary).

Comment: It actually [is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29327671/367456) but you normally don't wanna do it. /cc @Austin

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you're doing with that ternary operator is to decide on the key name. The element is going to be put into the array no matter what, it's right there in the array literal declaration.

The best you could do with an inline expression is something like this:

```
['foo' => 'bar'] + (true ? [] : ['baz' => 42])
```

Practically, you should probably better write:

```
$arr = ['foo' => 'bar'];
if (true) {
    $arr['baz'] = 42;
}
```

Writing more compact code is not always the best goal to have, it needs to be readable and understandable first of all.

Comment: Because this is tagged under php-5.3 it might be better not to use the short array syntax that is only available in 5.4+. But the answer is still correct.

Comment: Thank you, I went with the second method and the code still reads cleanly!

Comment: The "no matter what" is the key-point here. You can make it fail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29327671/367456 :)

Comment: @MáximaAlekz If you’re insinuating that the unreadable version is faster: it’s not. Secondarily, both Google and Facebook are heavily investing in their own languages and/or compilers; they’re solving the performance issue at the compiler level, not the code level (up to a point, obviously). Further, given the enormous team sizes and code bases in both companies, I’m sure maintainability, which includes readability, matters extremely to them.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8.1 added support for unpacking string-keyed arrays so we can use now the following construction:

```php
$condition = true;

$arr = [
  'Item 1' => 'Some value',
    ...$condition ? ['Item 2' => 'Another Value'] : []
];
// Item 1 & Item 2
```

The variable was added only for readability, but anyway, an inline condition also works:

```php
$arr = [
  'Item 1' => 'Some value',
    ...false ? ['Item 2' => 'Another Value'] : []
];
// Only Item 1
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be only possible by invalidating the statement.

For example you take a value for key that PHP can't handle (e.g. an array) and whenever you don't want to add the entry, you use that key.

The principle is actually similar to what you've outline with the `NULL` value:

```
Array(
    'Item 1' => 'Some value',
    TRUE ? array() : 'Item 2' => 'Another Value'
)
```

The downside of this is that the code is bulky, not clear to read and gives warnings:

> Warning: Illegal offset type

So I add this answer more for completeness.

Full example ([online demo](https://eval.in/306164)):

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP Ternary statement within Associative Array to set both key & value?
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29327671/367456
 */

var_dump(
    Array(
        'Item 1'                   => 'Some value',
        TRUE  ? array() : 'Item 2' => 'Another Value',
        FALSE ? array() : 'Item 3' => 'Just Another Value',
    )
);
```

Comment: That's actually pretty amazing, even if you should never ever do this.